# Strange behaviour sending IGMP on multi IP address for interface

Tags: multicast

I'd be glad to have some info/clue on the behavior in the followings situation:

There are `eth0` with IP address 10.10.10.10 and `eth0:1` with IP address 20.20.20.20.

IGMP join and leave shall be send from 20.20.20.20 IP.

Initially, there was no IGMP join at all. Checking the IP tables, it was found that:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       igmp --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       igmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       igmp --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       igmp --  anywhere             anywhere
```

After flushing the the OUTPUT chain, IGMP join/leave is sent from the 10.10.10.10 IP.
After flushing the INPUT chain, the join is sent from the wanted 20.20.20.20 IP (the leave is still sent from the 10.10.10.10 IP, but this is less important for us right now).

It seems to be very strange for me and for the SW eng.

Any idea on this behaviour

Comment: That's a good example why you shouldn't use multiple IPv4 addresses on a single interface and expect consistent results: Some operations will just pick a random source address, e.g. whatever happens to be first in some internal data structure. Which can be influenced by seemingly unrelated operations, e.g. flushing some iptables-chains. (But people on the net will keep telling you that using multiple IPv4 addresses is a good idea). So the proper solution is design your network in such a way you don't have multple IPv4 address (e.g. with namespaces).

Comment: there is only single NIC

Comment: You can use network namespaces with a macvlan on a single NIC to have as many addresses as you want. Or other constructs, depending on what you want to do (which you didn't say).